# Metric Connections on a Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

A Lie group has three standard Cartan connections; the (-)-connection, the (0)-connection, and the (+)-connection. The (0)-connection is Levi-Civita with the associated metric the bi-invariant metric. The other two connections aren't Levi-Civita due to the presence of torsion. However, there's nothing to stop them a priori from being metric connections. My question is; are the minus and plus connections compatible with the bi-invariant metric? This seems reasonable but I can't find a reference.

Comment: 1) I don't know what the +/- connections are, and I suspect I'm not the only one. Perhaps you could provide definitions?

2) Have you tried to work it out from scratch? It should all reduce to a calculation involving the group and Lie algebra at the origin. 

Comment: The +/-/0 terminology is used in section 11 of Nomizu's paper "Invariant affine connections on homogeneous spaces" where he attributes the distinction, and possibly also the notation, to Cartan (I've not followed the references). A left invariant affine connection is determined by specifying a bilinear mapping from the Lie algebra to itself. As one takes as this bilinear mapping respectively minus the Lie bracket, the Lie bracket, or half the Lie bracket one gets the -/+/0 connection. 

Comment: Kobayashi and Numizu also mention these connections briefly in Chapter X (vol.2). They reference Cartan and Schouten.

Comment: You should be careful to specify which Lie groups you mean.  Not all Lie groups carry bi-invariant metrics (of any signature).  Thus, for example, the connected, nonabelian Lie group of dimension 2 does not have such a metric (or even a bi-invariant volume form, for that matter).  In this example, the $(0)$-connection does not preserve any metric.  As Élie Cartan remarked when he defined these connections, the $(+)$ and $(-)$ connections on any Lie group are flat, so they each necessarily preserve (many) metrics on the group.  If the $(0)$-connection preserves a metric, it is bi-invariant.

Comment: Good point Robert. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that, in general, Cartan connections need not be metric connections. 

Comment: @Oliver:  Unfortunately, the term 'Cartan connection' has come to have an entirely different meaning, one that does not apply to the three affine connections on a Lie group that were defined by Cartan.  It is true that the (0)-connection need not be a metric connection (as I explained above).  However, the $\pm$-connections *do* each preserve metrics (in fact, you can arbitrarily specify the metric at the origin in each case), but, unless the Lie group is abelian, they are not Levi-Civita because they are never torsion-free.  In that sense, they are not 'metric connections' in the usual sense.

Comment: @Oliver:  Oh, I forgot to add (or, rather, didn't have room to add in my comments above) that, *when a bi-invariant metric on $G$ exists*, the $\pm$-connections do preserve it.  This is because, as the answers below attest, the $+$-connection preserves every *right*-invariant metric and the $-$-connection preserves every *left*-invariant metric.

Comment: @Robert: By a Cartan connection I meant one for which the 1-parameter subgroups and geodesics coincide. I hadn't realized the meaning of this had changed. Sorry, I didn't read your earlier post carefully enough. Even though a Lie group may not admit a bi-invariant metric, it will always admit some Riemannina metric. By your comments above, the $\pm$-connections will be compatible with this metric. That's very interesting about the (0)-connection. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: @Oliver:  Oops.  You've misunderstood something; maybe the following statements will help:   1. There are *many* connections that share the same geodesics; in particular, the three connections written down by Cartan are not the only ones whose geodesics are the 1-parameter subgroups.   2. The metrics compatible with the $+$-connection (which are right-invariant) may not have *any* intersection with the metrics compatible with the $-$ connection (which are left-invariant).  In fact, these two sets of metrics have a common element *if and only if* there is at least one bi-invariant metric.

Comment: @Robert: I misunderstood what you said above about the (-)-connection. I thought you were saying that any flat connection would preserve $\it{any}$ metric. I see now you said many, not any! I did a search and found that there are examples of flat connections that are not comaptible with any metric. I'll look at Cartan's paper to get the details.

Comment: @Oliver:  There do exist flat connections that are not compatible with any metric, but that doesn't happen in this case.  A basis of the left-invariant vector fields gives a basis of sections that are parallel for the (-)-connection, while a basis of the right-invariant vector fields gives a basis of sections that are parallel for the (+)-connection.  Thus, each of these connections is not only flat, it has trivial holonomy as well.  In particular, each of these connections *does* preserve a metric, in fact, a $\frac12 d(d{+}1)$-parameter family of them, where $d$ is the dimension of $G$.

Comment: @Robert: That's interesting that there are flat connections with nontrivial holonomy. Thanks again for clearing things up for me.  

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Let  $\nabla$ be an arbitrary connection  on the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
The standard trick for expressing the Levi-Civita connection in terms of $g$ gives you,
for any 3 vector fields $X$, $Y$, $Z$:
$$Xg(Y,Z)+ Yg(Z,X)- Zg(X,Y)= N(X,Y,Z)  $$
$$+ g(T(X,Z),Y)+ g(T(Y,Z),X)- g(T(X,Y),Z) $$
$$ +2 g(\nabla_X Y,Z)- g([X,Y],Z) + g([X,Z],Y) + g([Y,Z],X),$$

where
$$ T(X,Y)=\nabla_X Y- \nabla_Y X -[X,Y]$$
is    the torsion of $\nabla$ and
$$
N(X,Y,Z)= \nabla_Xg(Y,Z)+ \nabla_Yg(Z,X)-\nabla_Zg(X,Y).
$$
This is the "non-metricity": $N=0\Leftrightarrow \nabla g=0$.

Now, turning to the case at hand: we define the $\pm$ and $0$ connections by
$$ (\nabla_X Y)_e=\epsilon [X,Y],$$ 
$ \epsilon = 1, 0, \frac{1}{2}$ respectively, so the torsion is
$$T(X,Y) = (2\epsilon -1)[X,Y]= \pm[X,Y]\textrm{ or } 0, $$
hence the names of the connections. But then you get
$$ 0 = N(X,Y,Z) -2\epsilon\left[ g([Z,Y],X) + g(Y,[Z,X]) \right],$$
and the second summand is zero due to bi-invariance, so   $N=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the answer is Yes.

the +/-/0 connections can be defined by, if $X,Y$ is the left invariant vector
$$\nabla_{X}Y=a[X,Y]$$
where $a=1,-1,0$.

The connection is metric for left invariant metric iff
$$0=\langle\nabla_{X}Y,Z\rangle+\langle Y,\nabla_{X}Z\rangle.$$

This is trival for the bi-invariant metric.

Comment: Thanks Shu. But as Robert pointed out, I had implicitly assumed the existence of a bi-invariant metric.